# How to find Square of a number inside a Factorial while loop in C?

Tags: c, visual-c++, factorial

I'm trying to create a program that not only calculate the factorial of a number but also display an output where the factorial is less than the square of that number.

These are the requirements: 
You type in a number between 3 to 9. 
It displays in output both its factorial and its square. 
If the factorial of the number inserted is less than the square of the number, Output the string "Gotcha!"

This is my code so far. Thank you

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#define MIN 3
#define MAX 9
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main()
{
int i, fact = 1, num;
printf("Enter a number:\n");
scanf_s("%d", &num);

while (num >= MIN || num <= MAX)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        fact = fact*i;
    }
    if (num < MIN || num > MAX)
    {
        printf("Out of range. Please try again.\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Factorial of %d is: %d\n", num, fact);
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Edit your source and and add headers there.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the square of the number by multiplying it by itself.

```
square = num * num;
printf("Square of %d is: %d\n", num, square);

if (fact < square)
    printf("Gotcha!\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

r.e. pragmatic approach, I agree with bodangly.

r.e. theory behind your question, lets dig into that a little...

edit: didn't look deeply enough, instead of never my answer should have been "mostly never (only twice for n=2 and n=3).

To recap your question:
   Given 'n' find out if the "factorial of n" is less than the "square of n".

We can summarize this as:

```
n! < n^2
```

Let's flip this around to make it easier to manipulate:

```
n! < n^2
n^2 > n!
n * n > n * (n-1) * (n-2) * .. * 1
```

If we divide each side by n, we get the following.

```
n > (n-1) * (n-2) * .. * 1
n > (n-1)!
```

So the question becomes: for what value(s) of n is n > (n-1)! ?
(spoiler alert: not very often)

Let's look to see when n > (n-1)!

Consider this table...

```
+------------+----+-----+----------+-------------------------+
| n > (n-1)! | n  | n-1 |  (n-1)!  |  notes...               |
+------------+----+-----+----------+-------------------------+
|       no   | 0  |  -1 |  undef   | (-1)! is undefined      |
|       no   | 1  |   0 |     1    | 0! is 1 by definition   |
|      yes   | 2  |   1 |     1    | 1! is 1 by definition   |
|      yes   | 3  |   2 |     2    | ( or 2 * 1 )            |
|       no   | 4  |   3 |     6    | ( or 3 * 2 * 1 )        |
|       no   | 5  |   4 |    24    | ( or 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 )    |
+------------+----+-----+----------+-------------------------+
```

Which means n **>** (n-1)!  is only true for n=2 and n=3.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I really appreciate it. I'll put that as a notes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN 3
#define MAX 9
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

enum {NO_ERRORS, ERROR};
enum {FALSE, TRUE};


int main()
{
    int i, fact = 1, num, valid = FALSE, sqr;

    while(!valid){

        printf("Enter a number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num < MIN && num > MAX){
            printf("Out of range. Please try again.\n");            
        }else{
            valid = TRUE;                       
        }
    }

    /* get the factorial */
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++){
        fact = fact * i;
    }

    /* get the square */
    sqr = num * num;

    /* output */
    if( fact < sqr){
        printf("%s\n", "Gotcha!");
    }else{
        printf("Factorial of %d is: %d\n", num, fact);
    }

    return NO_ERRORS;
}
```

Thanks